# Exactly what updates will I get with the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: release-management

Exactly what updates will I get with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Am I going to get updates on the Unity3D interface? The window manager? The core system? software like Firefox, VLC etc?

Comment: I guess you actually mean: *what are the differences between 13.10 and 14.04?*

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=difference+between+13.10+and+14.04

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you will receive newer, more up-to-date software (kernel, Firefox, VLC, etc.), and probably small improvements on the interface.

For a detailed, more technical description of what's new, see the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes).

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes in Ubuntu 14.04. For an official list of many of them, check out the release notes:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

Also, as linked therein, some information about new features is available through the blueprints list:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+specs